# How can I order snippets by application in django?

Tags: python, django, templates

I've got a site with a a number of applications, each one providing a section on the sidebar. Let's say one app is "companies" providing company management (list, add, remove) and one is "employee", allowing for employee management.

"companies" provides a section:

```
<div id="companies-sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="{% url 'company_add' %}">Add</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'company_remove' %}">Remove</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'company_list' %}">List</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Same for the "employees", with the `employees_` URLs respectively.

I would like to order the two snippets in the sidebar section based on the application. If I'm in the view for e.g. `company_list` (or `..._remove` or `add`), then the `companies_sidebar` snippet should be first. If I'm in the views corresponding to `employees_...`, then the `employees_sidebar` should be first.

The question is: How can I do it without flooding the templates with include-able snippets?

Some notes:

- I know this is not a normal UX pattern, where items change order.
- One solution would be to use custom (base.html?) templates for each app, with the changed items accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a custom template tag, `{% sidebar_snippets appname %}` that takes the current app name as an argument.  Then in the Python that implements sidebar_snippets, you can order the pieces any way you like.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Since it probably involves a loop through the installed applciations, would the result be cached?

Comment: You could implement your own caching of the resulting HTML.

Comment: Challenging... I think I'll do that (probably with a comma-separated list of apps instead...